# routing gallery actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, rails-routing

I am currently trying to put together a gallery system for a project with rails 3.  I feel that I should do this from scratch for more control and learning.  However, when I try to delete an image from `http://localhost:3000/admin/albums/33/images`, the delete button goes to `http://localhost:3000/admin/albums/1/images`.  It seems that the delete button takes the ID of the image chosen and instead of appending it at the end of the url, it replaces the album id in the url with it.  I need the delete button to call `http://localhost:3000/admin/albums/33/images/1` to delete that image.  I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

**view**

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
    <%= image.title %>
    <%= image.description %>
    <%= image.image_name %>
    <%= button_to "Delete", admin_album_images_path(image), :method => :delete, :style => "display: block;" %>
    <%= debug params %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
class Admin::ImagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @images = Image.all
    end
    def new
        @image = Image.new(params[:id])
    end
    def create
        @image = Image.new(params[:id])
        if @image.save
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully added image!"
            redirect_to [:admin, :albums, :image_name]
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end
    def show
    end
    def destroy
        @image = Image.find(params[:id])
        @image.destroy
        redirect_to admin_albums_path
    end
end
```

**Routes**

```
Admin::Application.routes.draw do
  get "albums/index"

  get "dashboard/index"

  namespace :admin do
    root :to => "dashboard#index"
    resources :dashboard
    resources :albums do
      resources :images
     end
    get "admin/album"
    end
    get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"
    # resources :users
  resources :basic
    root :to => "basic#index"
```

**image model**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :description, :image_name
    has_and_belongs_to_many :albums
end
```

**Album model**

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :description
    has_and_belongs_to_many :images,  :dependent => :destroy
    validates :title, :description, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: Nested resources doesn't work as normal resources, take a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `admin_album_images_path`, as a nested resource you'll need to specify both of the resources.

```
<%= button_to "Delete", admin_album_images_path(image.album,image), :method => :delete, :style => "display: block;" %>
```

Comment: this results in `No route matches {:format=>#<Image id: 1, title: nil, description: nil, image_name: nil, date: nil, album_id: nil>, :controller=>"admin/images", :album_id=>nil}`

Comment: it looks like your associations are wrong - you probably want to have `belongs_to :album` on your `Image` model instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`, and then change the `has_and_belongs_to_many` on `Album` to a `has_many :images, dependent: :destroy`